# how do i select the required attributes from a union of left join and right join

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables on which I am unable to perform full outer join so I am doing a union of left and right outer join.
each table has attributes like

`tableA - one,two,three,four`

`tableB - one,two,three,four`

```
(SELECT * FROM tableA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON 
tableA.two=tableB.two) 
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tableA 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tableB ON
tableA.two=tableB.two)
```

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to pull only a selection of the columns in each table?

Comment: i need to select only one,two colums from the union of both queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to alias the tables

```
SELECT a1.one, a1.two, b1.one, b1.two 
FROM tableA a1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB b1 
  ON a1.two=b1.two
UNION
SELECT a2.one, a2.two, b2.one, b2.two
FROM tableA a2 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tableB b2 
ON a2.two=b2.two;
```

As an aside, the "`UNION ALL` and exclusion `JOIN`" method described [on this page](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/) is a more reliable way of implementing `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL.